# Vue Prism Editor - set tabSize

Tags: vue.js, tab-size, vue-prism-editor

im currently digging through the github page, but Im unable to figure out how to set the tabSize property on my prism editor, if anyone has any experience and is willing to share it I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: just set tabSize in the component should be fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-prism-editor-example-forked-yww7c?file=/src/App.vue:297-309

Comment: well the snippet you sent worked great in the online editor it for some reason did not work for me, this is my code: `<template>
        <prism-editor class="my-editor" v-model="code" :highlight="highlighter" line-numbers></prism-editor>
    </template>

 
    <div id="app">
        <prism-editor class="my-editor height-200" v-model="code" :highlight="highlighter" line-numbers></prism-editor>
    </div>`
any idea of what couldve gone wrong?

Comment: no problem as well. can you make a codesandbox to simulate your case?

Comment: sure thing! this link should do the trick: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sunset-xu0sz also, you might not see anything and will have to reset the page viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer here as I placed in code snippet for you to play with.
There is a problem on the umd script where it cannot recognise `tabSize` as a valid props.
Therefore, you can use `tab-size` to overcome this.

P.S. move tab size to be part of vue data to avoid complaining the type.

Here is the code snippet for you to test it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-prism-editor/dist/prismeditor.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css" />
    <style>
        .height-200 {
            height: 200px
        }

        .my-editor {
            /* we dont use `language-` classes anymore so thats why we need to add background and text color manually */
            background: #2d2d2d;
            color: #ccc;

            /* you must provide font-family font-size line-height. Example:*/
            font-family: Fira code, Fira Mono, Consolas, Menlo, Courier, monospace;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        /* optional class for removing the outline */
        .prism-editor__textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <prism-editor class="my-editor height-200" v-model="code" :highlight="highlighter" line-numbers :tab-size="tabSize">
        </prism-editor>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.*"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-prism-editor"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/prismjs/prism.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <script src="./src/index.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: () => ({
                code: "code",
                tabSize: 8
            }),
            methods: {
                highlighter(code) {
                    // js highlight example
                    return Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.js, "js");
                }
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: works great! thank you both for all your help and patience, I appreciate it a lot!